# Return error message from flask to same form in a modal

Tags: python, ajax, flask, modal-dialog

HTML: I have a 'sign-up' form in a modal (index.html)

JS: The form data is posted to a python flask function: /signup_user

```
  $(function () {
$('#signupButton').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/signup_user',
    method: 'POST',
    data: $('#signupForm').serialize()
  })
    .done(function (data) {
      console.log('success callback 1', data)
    })
    .fail(function (xhr) {
      console.log('error callback 1', xhr);
    })
  })
});
```

Python/Flask:

```
@app.route('/signup_user', methods=['POST'])
def signup_user():
#Request data from form and send to database
#Check that username isn't already taken
#if the username is not already taken  
    if new_user:
        users.insert_one(new_user)
        message = "Success"
        return message
#else if ussername is taken, send message to user viewable in the modal
    else:
        message = "Failure"
        return message
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

I cannot figure out how to get the flask function to return the "Failure" message to the form in the modal so that the user can change the username.

Right now, as soon as I click the submit button the form/modal disappears and the 'Failure' message refreshes the entire page to a blank page with the word Failure.
How do I get the error message back to display in the form/modal?

Comment: Every answer below still has the modal disappear after clicking the button and the 'Success' or 'Failure' text overwriting the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you have a redirect function in your **signup_user** script at the end. That is why the page refreshes and shows the message that is returned by the script.

So remove this line:

```
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

And update your Ajax code to this:

```
$(function () {
 $('#signupButton').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "postride.php",
    data:dataString,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#signupMessages').html(data);
    }
 });
});
```

Python/Flask:

```
@app.route('/signup_user', methods=['POST'])
def signup_user():
#Request data from form and send to database
#Check that username isn't already taken
#if the username is not already taken  
if new_user:
    users.insert_one(new_user)
    message = "Success"
    return message
#else if ussername is taken, send message to user viewable in the modal
else:
    message = "Failure"
    return message
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I removed:  return redirect(url_for('index')) and replaced with return.

I created a div in the form for the message:  $("#signupMessages").html(data);
Neither solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the correct syntax for AJAX according to https://codehandbook.org/python-flask-jquery-ajax-post/

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/signup_user',
            data: $('#signupForm').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

You could also try getJSON for shorthand:

```
        $.getJSON('/signup_user',
            $('#signupForm').serialize(),
            function(res) {
            console.log(res)
        });
```

UPDATED:
In my own use, I have found that `methods=['POST']` isn't necessary for ajax calls in flask's @app.route. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The thing i will do is to first check if we're reaching the function, with a breakpoint on the function, for this you can use the python debugger, just putting this line:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

(just at the beginning of the function)

so it will be like this:

```
@app.route('/signup_user', methods=['POST'])
def signup_user():
#Request data from form and send to database
#Check that username isn't already taken
#if the username is not already taken  

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
if new_user:
    users.insert_one(new_user)
    message = "Success"
    return message
#else if ussername is taken, send message to user viewable in the modal
else:
    message = "Failure"
    return message
```

So when you finally run the code and send the request, you should see the console with the python server running that is stopped by a like with this -> (pdb)
(if you dont see that "(pdb)" in the console just press enter to see if it appears)

if not stopped then you're just not entering the function,

otherwise you're in the function, good.. now let's take a look and debug a little bit, the first thing you could check is if we can enter in the else statement.. you can pass line by line just entering the letter "n" and pressing enter, so keep going until you enter in the else part, if so then you're actually returning the text "Failure"

if not, then you've just discovered a part of the problem..

some other options that you should check:

.- try pass parameters to the ajax function like the dataType: 'json'

.- try to see if you need to enable CORS for the python app

.- keep debuggin line by line

Good luck on that buddy

Answer (score 0):

I got this working after much testing;
my ajax call needed:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Also, my python function needed to have the redirect changed to a return.
So [Architect](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10354156/architect) was correct.

I also noticed that my  wasn't appearing in the source view of the page, so there may have been some caching issue.

All contributors were correct in some way. It was just that I had a couple of different things wrong.